# Initial tab selected by the URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("ul.iwTabs").each(function() {
    $("li a", this).first().addClass("selected");
    initialTabId = $("li a", this).first().attr("href");
    $(initialTabId).css("display", "block");
    });


    $("ul.iwTabs li a").click(function () {
        newTabId = $(this).attr("href");
        listElement = $(this).parent().parent();
        oldTabId = $("a.selected", listElement).attr("href");

        $("a.selected", listElement).removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

        $(oldTabId).css("display", "none");
        $(newTabId).css("display", "block");
        return false;
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class='iwTabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'><div id="cupons">Meus cupons</div></a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'><div id="creditos">Meus créditos</div></a></li>
</ul>

...

<div id='tab1' class='iwTabs'>...content...</div>
<div id='tab2' class='iwTabs'>...content...</div>
```

This works fine, but I want the user to enter the URL: `example.com/my_page#tab2` and get to the page with the `tab2` opened. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href=ui.tab;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think a good place to start would be this article on assigning distinct URLs to different parts of your application.

http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs